# Array input type with typeahead utilizing Meteor Autoform

Tags: meteor, schema, typeahead.js, meteor-autoform

I have [typeahead](https://github.com/comerc/meteor-autoform-typeahead) input type working for an input field.

I want to be able to use it like I would other [Meteor.ObjectID] types in my schema (or potentially any arrayed type).  `{{> afQuickField}}` should recognize the array and wrap it in the 'afArrayField' template, giving it the wonderful add/remove buttons and functionality and also returning an array.

Currently, I just get the one instance of the input and an error message on submission saying that this value must be an array.

I'm scouring [autoform's](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) code base looking for how this is implemented on other input types, but so far no luck as there's a LOT of code. I would accept just a pointer to the code that does this currently.

**More info**

I found `AutoForm.getInputType` function in [autoform-api.js](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/master/autoform-api.js). I may have to overload this to get my desired behavior. Better alternatives are still welcome!

**Tried also**

So I thought the trick might be it responds to an array of nested schemas. No overload necessary, just put my typeahead field into a separate schema, and nested it in my main schema.

```
myTypeahead = new SimpleSchema({
  item:{
    type: Meteor.ObjectID,
    autoform: {
      type: "typeahead"
    },
    ...
  }
});

myMainSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  itemId:{
    type: [myTypeahead]
  }
});
```

And that set up the ability to add/remove the fields. The down side? Now typeahead is throwing errors like mad.

```
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastIndexOf' of undefined
at inflectedLabel (/packages/aldeed_simple-schema.js?8fda161c43c0ba62801a10b0dfcc3eab75c6db88:2125:44)
at SimpleSchema.getDefinition (/packages/aldeed_simple-schema.js?8fda161c43c0ba62801a10b0dfcc3eab75c6db88:2670:30)
at Object.autoFormGetOptionsForField [as _getOptionsForField] (/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?95e4d3c1e4a248502de2befc9436a32b15999fa3:2690:12)
at Object.afOptionsFromSchema (/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?95e4d3c1e4a248502de2befc9436a32b15999fa3:1519:12)
at bindDataContext (/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2727:16)
at Blaze._wrapCatchingExceptions (/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1606:16)
at Object.Spacebars.call (/packages/spacebars.js?7f53771c84a2eafac2b561c9796dda0d8af8e7f5:171:18)
at /client/template.person.js?684475f8f7f0a8f9fe76ecebd81f50a84a03f24d:142:30
at Blaze._TemplateWith.wrappedArgFunc (/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2639:14)
at null.<anonymous> (/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2445:26)

Exception in template helper: TypeError: undefined is not a function
at /packages/aldeed_autoform.js?95e4d3c1e4a248502de2befc9436a32b15999fa3:212:34
at /packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:176:29
at _.each._.forEach (/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
at Function._.map._.collect (/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:175:5)
at Object.getSelectOptions (/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?95e4d3c1e4a248502de2befc9436a32b15999fa3:211:25)
at getInputData (/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?95e4d3c1e4a248502de2befc9436a32b15999fa3:1783:37)
at Object.afFieldInputContext (/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?95e4d3c1e4a248502de2befc9436a32b15999fa3:6999:17)
at bindDataContext (/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2727:16)
at Blaze._wrapCatchingExceptions (/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1606:16)
at Object.Spacebars.call (/packages/spacebars.js?7f53771c84a2eafac2b561c9796dda0d8af8e7f5:171:18)


Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'class' of undefined
at Object.addClass (/packages/aldeed_autoform.js?95e4d3c1e4a248502de2befc9436a32b15999fa3:641:20)
at Object.Template.afTypeahead.helpers.atts (/client/quickForm/autoform-typeahead.js?5037f57aba2aa1b9ec271e4ade183a5d126781e5:43:29)
at bindDataContext (/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2727:16)
at Blaze._wrapCatchingExceptions (/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1606:16)
at Spacebars.call (/packages/spacebars.js?7f53771c84a2eafac2b561c9796dda0d8af8e7f5:171:18)
at Spacebars.mustacheImpl (/packages/spacebars.js?7f53771c84a2eafac2b561c9796dda0d8af8e7f5:108:25)
at Object.Spacebars.attrMustache (/packages/spacebars.js?7f53771c84a2eafac2b561c9796dda0d8af8e7f5:124:39)
at /client/quickForm/template.autoform-typeahead.js?e749e8ff2e104b2c1b5d2ca1f3f7bf538c5790e7:17:22
at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2043:12)
at Blaze._HTMLJSExpander.def.visitAttributes (/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1962:21)


Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: Cannot read property 'atts' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'atts' of undefined
at Template.afTypeahead.rendered (/client/quickForm/autoform-typeahead.js?5037f57aba2aa1b9ec271e4ade183a5d126781e5:74:16)
at null.<anonymous> (/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:3008:21)
at /packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1733:14
at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (/packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:2043:12)
at /packages/blaze.js?efa68f65e67544b5a05509804bf97e2c91ce75eb:1732:15
at Tracker.flush (/packages/tracker.js?517c8fe8ed6408951a30941e64a5383a7174bcfa:448:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this same error, but I'm not sure if it was for the same reason.  What does your entire {{> afQuickField }} look like?  I found that removing the "options" from the tag, or using options=afOptionsFromSchema made the error go away.

Using options="auto" no longer works.

Comment: I actually abandoned typeahead altogether for the time being. Wrote my own... I think the one out there isn't compatible with newer versions of autoform.